# Error in using Rcpp in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, rcpp, r-markdown

I want to compare the speed of a ordinary R-loop and a loop with Rcpp. I need this comparison for a small documentation and that's why it have to be in use in rmarkdown. The code is:

```
for_R <- function(n){
  a <- 0
  for(i in 1:n){
    a = a + i
  }
  return(a)
}

Rcpp::cppFunction('
        int for_C(int n) {
          int a = 0;
          for(int i = 1; i < (n+1); i++) {
            a += i;
          }
          return a;
        }', showOutput = TRUE)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark('R-Schleife' = for_R(10000),
                               'C-Schleife' = for_C(10000))
```

The output from the cppFunction is:

```
## C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB -o "sourceCpp_71184.dll" "" "file30c7c6b798b.cpp"
```

I'm a little bit confused about the following error that only appears when i knitr the file:

```
## Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, showOutput = showOutput, : Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

If i run the code in the console everything works fine and without any error. I also try to knitr the Rmd file from different directions, but that also failed.

Some information about the software:

- R version is 2.3.1
- Rtools installed in C:
- I use everything in combination with Rstudio Version 0.99.465

I searched in other posts, but everytime i found something about this error it wasn't in rmarkdown. I installed a new operating system (windows 8.1) and after finishing it and install all the programms the error occurs. I would be happy if somebody could help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code builds for me (under Linux).  But I'd use `sourceCpp()` and put everything in a .cpp file:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int for_C(int n) {
  int a = 0;
  for(int i = 1; i < (n+1); i++) {
    a += i;
  }
  return a;
}

/*** R
for_R <- function(n) {
  a <- 0
  for(i in 1:n){
    a = a + i
  }
  return(a)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark('R-Schleife' = for_R(10000),
                               'C-Schleife' = for_C(10000))
*/
```

which, when `sourceCpp()`-ed, produces the result:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/daniel.cpp")

R> for_R <- function(n) {
+   a <- 0
+   for(i in 1:n){
+     a = a + i
+   }
+   return(a)
+ }

R> microbenchmark::microbenchmark('R-Schleife' = for_R(10000),
+                                'C-Schleife' = for_C(10000))
Unit: microseconds
       expr      min       lq       mean   median       uq       max neval
 R-Schleife 4351.736 4680.954 6300.95103 4774.863 5166.111 70614.405   100
 C-Schleife    5.457    6.618    9.80134    9.746   11.471    50.236   100
R>
```

Comment: Here is the same problem. In the console it works absolutely perfekt, but when i use the code in a code chunk in rmarkdown and knit the file the same error occurs. I tried to reinstall `R`, but that didn't fix it. I can craft the output by copy and pasting by myself from the console but i'm not very satisfied with that.

Comment: You are not supposed to _use sourceCpp() within a RMarkdown snippet_ as those are `sourceCpp()`'ed themselves.  Mayne that is your problem?

Comment: Yes i think that's it. I tried it on another computer and get the same error. Is there a way to use `cppFunction()` or `sourceCpp()` in a `RMarkdown` code chunk?

Comment: You can mock it.  Do it twice, one evaluate and not shown and once shown but not evaluated.

Comment: Sorry i think i'm to foolisch for that. Do you mean in one chunk the option `echo=FALSE` and one with `eval=FALSE`?

Comment: Yes,  that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I looked back on my problem today and now I got an answer. I recognize that my path wasn't correct. After fixing that dumb mistake everything works fine. Thanks again to Dirk.